# how to update a particular value in json?

Tags: c#, json

I am using newtonsoft json library. I want to update value of a token "Status" from false to true in following json. How can I do that?:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "Status": false,
    "crs": {
        "type": "EPSG",
        "properties": {
            "code": 28992
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what have u tried so far?

Comment: @NewtonSheikh nothing. i can't see any Setter in JObject.

Comment: check the solution from @Nunners

Comment: You can use `JObject.Parse` to parse it an object. Then you can try to modify it. please clarify where you want change it

Comment: @NewtonSheikh caught you :P

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can deserialize it, modify the value and serialize it again

```
dynamic jsonObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
jsonObject.Status = true;
var modifiedJsonString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObject);
```

Comment: thanks, havn't expected a cleaner way than this. though I guess it must be kept in try-catch to avoid cases when Status is not a part of json. right?

Comment: Well not exaclty, that depends what you want to do, if Status doesn't exist that piece of code will add it. If you don't want that then check for jsonObject.Status != null. But the code won't fail and throw an exception.

Answer (score 4):

In this case, the name of the token is known (Status). However, when the name of the token known at only runtime (when name passed as parameter).

```
string UpdateTokenValue(string jsonString, string TokenName, string newValue)
{
    JObject jsonObj = (JObject)Netwonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonstring);
    jsonObj.Property(TokenName).Value = newValue;
    return NewtonSoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj);
}
```

Comment: How can i update multiple JsonTokens with new values. Example: how to update `type` in `crs` and `code` in `properties` in above example